# How to rank column accordingly using case_when?

Tags: r, dplyr, ranking, case-when

I wanted to create another column (called delayGrade) where the top 10% of values (closest to 0) from another column (averageDelay) get assigned the letter 'A', the next 25% 'B', and the remaining 'C'. I figured I could use a case_when function to do so, but not sure how to go about doing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is toy data frame and solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  averageDelay = rnorm(10)
)

df %>%
  mutate(
    delayGrade = case_when(
      averageDelay < quantile(averageDelay, .1)  ~ "A",
      averageDelay < quantile(averageDelay, .35) ~ "B",
      TRUE                                       ~ "C"
    )
  ) %>% 
  arrange(averageDelay) # Not necissary, but improves readability

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   averageDelay delayGrade
          <dbl>      <chr>
 1  -1.57878473          A
 2  -1.00129022          B
 3  -0.34245100          B
 4  -0.08652020          B
 5  -0.05240453          C
 6   0.15732711          C
 7   0.21509389          C
 8   0.34202367          C
 9   0.90296373          C
10   0.90820894          C
```